# Does ClassLoader.resolveClass() actually do anything?

Tags: java, classloader

This is the definition of `java.lang.ClassLoader.resolveClass(Class)` in [OpenJDK 20+10](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-20+10/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/ClassLoader.java#L1222):

```
    protected final void resolveClass(Class<?> c) {
        if (c == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
    }
```

It appears to be doing nothing except checking that the argument is non-null. And yet, the doc comment claims:

```
    /**
     * Links the specified class.  This (misleadingly named) method may be
     * used by a class loader to link a class.  If the class {@code c} has
     * already been linked, then this method simply returns. Otherwise, the
     * class is linked as described in the "Execution" chapter of
     * <cite>The Java Language Specification</cite>.
```

Does calling this method actually do anything useful? Since it is `final`, subclasses cannot override it to make it do anything different. Is it literally a does-nothing-except-null-check method, or does the JVM somehow magically intercept its invocation and do something more?

Comment: it only checks if the class is found i guess

Comment: @Jens: not sure what you mean by "only checks if the class is found". This method is called from `ClassLoader.loadClass(String name, boolean resolve)` when `resolve` is true – but if there is no class by that name, it fails with `ClassNotFoundException` before it gets to that line. Class loaders (whether in the JDK or external) which override `loadClass()` generally follow the same pattern. Using this method as some kind of class existence check must be rather rare (I've never seen it), and is not its intended usage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does calling this method actually do anything useful?

In Java 8 this method called a native method `resolveClass0`.  I haven't looked at the Java 8 native method's implementation.  It might already have been a no-op.

From Java 9 onwards it simply checks that the argument `c` is not `null`.  So ... now, the answer is clearly No.

There were significant changes to the implementations of classloaders between Java 8 and 9 (see https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/9-all-relnotes.html).  This were due in part to the need to support Java 9 modules.

My guess is that the Java 9 classloader changes made the `resolveClass` method either redundant or unhelpful .  But rather than causing rework for people with custom classloaders, the Java team simply turned the method into a no-op.

Anyhow, the javadoc comment says:

> Links the specified class.  This (misleadingly named) method may be
> used by a class loader to link a class.  If the class `c` has
> already been linked, then this method simply returns. Otherwise, the
> class is linked as described in the "Execution" chapter of "The Java Language Specification".

I can think of two possible explanations for making the method a no-op now:

1. In current (Java 9+) classloader implementations, the class could always have been linked earlier, making the call redundant.
2. They have decided that a custom classloader should no longer be allowed to decide when the class should be linked.

   - Maybe it caused complications that would be difficult to deal with in the updated classloader implementations?
   - Maybe it was thought to be a flaw in the original design?

Comment: It seems, `resolveClass(…)` never had any effect, at least for a long time. The oldest I just tried was Java 6. So the only thing that changed, is that an obsolete native call does not happen. Seems to be in accordance with [this finding](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8226540?focusedCommentId=14323291&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14323291)